# Python bytearray initialization from mutating sequence

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x

I want to generate a byte array with a sequence of values starting from some initial value, such as:

```
def generateTestcase(n, init):
    v = init
    data = bytearray(n)
    for i in range(n):
        data[i] = v
        # mutate v in some arbitrary fashion, but stay a valid byte value...
        v = (v+1 if v < 255 else 0)
```

This works, I'm just wondering if there a more pythonic syntax where the initialization can be passed into the bytearray constructor similar to how a range object can be used: `bytearray(range(20))`.

Ideally a solution would not necessarily increment v by 1.  Maybe it doubles it, or adds 3, or whatever, always wrapping the result to fit in a byte.

Is the best solution to create a custom range-like object or is there some way to use a lambda here that captures v & n and returns the right list of values (preferrably without creating a complete list copy in memory first, but return the values as required)?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You could write a generator to define a custom iterator:

```py
def generate(n, init):
    v = init
    for i in range(n):
        yield v
        # mutate v here
        v = (v+1 if v < 255 else 0)
```

And then use it:

```py
bytearray(generate(79, 1))
```

This separates the independent concerns of generating the data and storing the data.